# Does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n^2} 1}{\sum_{i=1}^n i}$ result into 2?

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

How does the following limit $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n^2} 1}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n i}$$ result into 2?
Something like:

$$\frac{1+3+5+7+9+11+13+15+\dots}{1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+\dots}$$

Can I plot this in WolframAlpha?

Comment: Type "plot [sum 1, j=1 to n^2]/[sum i, i=1 to n] n=0 to 1000" into wolframalpha.

Answer (score 10):

The notation $$\sum_{i=1}^{M}1$$ means you sum $1$, $M$ times, so in your case you sum $1$, $n^2$ times, so

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n^2} 1=\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n^2\text{ times} }=n^2$$

while

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i=\frac 1 2n(n+1)$$

which means your expression is $$=\frac{2n^2}{n(n+1)}$$ $$=\frac{2n}{n+1}$$ and this goes to $2$ as $n\to\infty$.

---

Let

$$S_n=1+2+\cdots n$$

Then $$S_n=1+2+\cdots+(n-1) +n\\S_n=n+(n-1)+\cdots + 2 +1$$

and summing column-wise gives:
 $$2S_n=(n+1)+(n-1+2)+(n-2+3)+\cdots +(3+n-2)+(2+n-1)+(n+1)$$

$$2S_n=(n+1)+(n+1)+\cdots+(n+1)=n(n+1)$$ Thus $$S_n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

In $\Sigma$ notation, $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k=\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k+1)$$

so $$S_n+S_n=2S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (n+1)=n(n+1)$$

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i=\frac 1 2n(n+1)$$ <- but, that wasn't the starting point in the formula above? Did you skip some steps?

Comment: @user8005 What do you mean?

Comment: Could you add more steps to your explaination?